# Tokenise line containing string literals

Tags: python, string, parsing

Using `str.split` on `"print 'Hello, world!' times 3"` returns the list `["print", "'Hello,", "world!'", "times", "3"]`. However, I want the result `["print", "'Hello, world!'", "times", "3"]`. How can I do that?

Comment: *"it's pretty obvious that that's not the desired result"* - to you, perhaps. Looks fine to me, assuming that all you're doing is splitting on spaces. Also that's a set, not a list, so order isn't guaranteed.

Comment: Regex is your key

Comment: @NeilGatenby Sorry, meant `foo.split()`... New to Python, still memorising the functions :)

Comment: @JosephCaruso why would you have to memorise anything? You should be copying and pasting a [mcve] from your interpreter into the question; then you'd get the method name and list literal syntax correct. As it stands, the answer to your question is *"by writing some code rather than assuming `.split` will do it"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will capture the quotes, if you want them.

```
import re

s = "print 'hello, world!' 3 times"
re.findall(r'(\w+|\'.+\')',s)
```

Comment: No modifying this one was necessary; it worked perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to exclude the words in quote out of the *split*, you could use [`shlex.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split):

```
import shlex

s = "print 'Hello, world!' times 3"
print(shlex.split(s))
# ['print', 'Hello, world!', 'times', '3']
```

Comment: I was gonna suggest str.split("'"), which retains the single quotes - and still leaves more work to do ... but this looks nicer

Comment: Wow, very useful function! That can easily be modified to handle re-adding the quotes with something simple along the lines of (if s contains ' ' then s = '"' + s + '"'), so that perfectly answered my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`.split()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) function splits the `str` based on the delimiter. The default delimiter is a `blank space`. It doesn't care about the `'` within your string. In case you want to treat words within `'` as a single word. You should be using [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) library or you may write `regex` expression. Surely, `split()` is not what you are looking for.